# Dealing with huge select lists

Tags: list, select

I often use select lists with my projects but when it comes to a huge select list, I couldn't find a solution. I need a easy, plug and play solution for solution will be used in a few places.

When you have a select box or text box to be filled from a model data, I want to show user a text box, right side of text box, there should be a button to choice the value. Upon clicking that button, popup or a modal will be opened and I filter all the records and find my value, upon clicking value, modal or popup closes and I get choosen value to form control.

İmagine you have a text box to choose your customer, and among 2500 customer,

PS:don't suggest autocomplete, don't want to accomplish it.

Comment: What language is this, or anything specific? And could you add a sketch or something, that might simplify things.

Comment: my frontend language is html,javascript , backend is django.
dont want to do it all with complicated js scripts, cause it can easily get complicated. Need a modular solution.

Comment: There is a User Experience question about the best UI approach that's related to this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/1944/27501  I particularly liked this suggestion: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/2250/27501

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you look at something like Chozen plugin http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. It allows you to easily search large select lists

Comment: imagine I need to filter customers via city, county and name etc...
I need a grid in opening window and choosen customer id will be dropped to the related field

Comment: http://www.advocotek.com/demo/enhancedv2/index.php?module=Accounts&action=EditView&return_module=Accounts&return_action=index

Check this url, u can see arrow icons opening a popup window and allows you to selected record to return to main dialog.
is it achieveable with bootstrap modals?